# How to create a google map from information contained in a database

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have been following this article
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 that describes how to create a google map with pins from information contained in a database.

I have converted the example to work with my existing data contained in a Microsoft SQL Database it the extract is working well.  My problem is the initial map contains over 1000 pins so I need to filter it for analysis.

Next I crated a HTML form with check boxes so a user can select different categories overlayed on the map and leave off the ones they don't want.

To test I have just the follwoing in my forms action=

```
<form action="GenerateXML.php" method="post">
```

And modified GenerateXML.php to build a query based on the $_POST array passed in.  As expected this displays my filtered XML in the browser.

Fantastic!  I think I'm really close now but I can't figure out how to load the map from my submit button instead of from "function load()"

I thought of calling a javascript function from the form like this

```
<form name="form" action="PortfolioMap.html" onsubmit="return reloadResults(form)" method="POST">
```

Which does call a function and return back to the same form afterwards.

```
function reloadResults()    
{
    alert("Hi There");
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Portfolio");
    $.post('GenerateXML.php', {elements: elements})
}
```

Although I'm just guessing now how to pass the $_POST array to GenerateXML.php and redraw the map.  The above code doesn't do anything and just redraws the map with no pins as nothing is passed in from the xml (I think).

Here is the full PortfolioMap.html I'm working on.

Any ideas how to redraw the map with the information from my form?

Thanks
David.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Portfolio Maps Example</title>
    <style>
        html, body 
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map 
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 350px; 
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .CheckBoxTable 
        {
            display: table; 
            width: 50%;
        }
        .CheckBoxRow {display: table-row; }
        .CheckBoxCell 
        {
            display: table-cell; 
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            padding: 1px 5px; 
        }
    </style>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY API KEY>"
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var customIcons = 
    {
        Black:      {icon: 'black.png'},
        Blue:       {icon: 'blue.png'},
        Gold:       {icon: 'gold.png'},
        Grey:       {icon: 'grey.png'},
        Green:      {icon: 'green.png'},
        Lime:       {icon: 'lime.png'},
        Mustard:    {icon: 'mustard.png'},
        Olive:      {icon: 'olive.png'},
        Orange:     {icon: 'orange.png'},
        Pink:       {icon: 'pink.png'},
        Purple:     {icon: 'purple.png'},
        Red:        {icon: 'red.png'},
        Teal:       {icon: 'teal.png'},
        Yellow:     {icon: 'yellow.png'},
        CCBlack:    {icon: 'ccblack.png'},
        CCBlue:     {icon: 'ccblue.png'},
        CCGold:     {icon: 'ccgold.png'},
        CCLime:     {icon: 'cclime.png'},
        CCOlive:    {icon: 'ccolive.png'},
        CCPink:     {icon: 'ccpink.png'},
        CCPurple:   {icon: 'ccpurple.png'},
        CCRed:      {icon: 'ccred.png'},
        CCTeal:     {icon: 'ccteal.png'},
        CCYellow:   {icon: 'ccyellow.png'}, 
        YSBlack:    {icon: 'ysblack.png'},
        YSBlue:     {icon: 'ysblue.png'},
        YSGold:     {icon: 'ysgold.png'},
        YSLime:     {icon: 'yslime.png'},
        YSOlive:    {icon: 'ysolive.png'},
        YSPink:     {icon: 'yspink.png'},
        YSPurple:   {icon: 'yspurple.png'},
        YSRed:      {icon: 'ysred.png'},
        YSTeal:     {icon: 'ysteal.png'},
        YSYellow:   {icon: 'ysyellow.png'}, 
    };

    function load() 
    {
        refreshMap();
    }

    function refreshMap()
    {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
        {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9119, 151.1015),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        downloadUrl("GenerateXML.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon
            });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
        }); 
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        // alert("Debug 2 " + url );
        // alert("Debug 3 " + callback );
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
    }

    function reloadResults()    
    {
        alert("Hi There");
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Portfolio");
        $.post('GenerateXML.php', {elements: elements})
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">
    <div id="userForm" >

    <form name="form" action="PortfolioMap.html" onsubmit="return reloadResults(form)" method="POST"> 
    <!-- <form action="GenerateXML.php" method="post"> -->
    <fieldset>
        <legend> <H2>Select Elements to Display</h2></legend>
        <div class="CheckBoxTable">
            <div class="CheckoxRow">
                General
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "blackPortfolio"  value = "Black" />
                    <label for = "blackPortfolio">Black</label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "bluePortfolio"  value = "Blue" />
                    <label for = "bluePortfolio"> Blue </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "goldPortfolio" value = "Gold" />
                    <label for = "goldPortfolio"> Gold </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "greyPortfolio" value = "Grey" />
                    <label for = "greyPortfolio"> Grey </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "greenPortfolio" value = "Green" />
                    <label for = "greenPortfolio"> Green </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "limePortfolio" value = "Lime" />
                    <label for = "limePortfolio"> Lime </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "mustardPortfolio" value = "Mustard" />
                    <label for = "mustardPortfolio"> Mustard </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "olivePortfolio" value = "Olive" />
                    <label for = "olivePortfolio"> Olive </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "orangePortfolio" value = "Orange" />
                    <label for = "orangePortfolio"> Orange </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "pinkPortfolio" value = "Pink" />
                    <label for = "pinkPortfolio"> Pink </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "purplePortfolio" value = "Purple" />
                    <label for = "purplePortfolio"> Purple </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "redPortfolio" value = "Red" />
                    <label for = "redPortfolio"> Red </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "tealPortfolio" value = "Teal" />
                    <label for = "tealPortfolio"> Teal </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yellowPortfolio" value = "Yellow" />
                    <label for = "yellowPortfolio"> Yellow </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CheckoxRow">
                Manager Name 1
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccblackPortfolio" value = "CCBlack" />
                    <label for = "ccblackPortfolio">CCBlack</label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccbluePortfolio" value = "CCBlue" />
                    <label for = "ccbluePortfolio"> CCBlue </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccgoldPortfolio" value = "CCGold" />
                    <label for = "ccgoldPortfolio"> CCGold </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "cclimePortfolio" value = "CCLime" />
                    <label for = "cclimePortfolio"> CCLime </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccolivePortfolio" value = "CCOlive" />
                    <label for = "ccolivePortfolio"> CCOlive </label>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccpinkPortfolio" value = "CCPink" />
                    <label for = "ccpinkPortfolio"> CCPink </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "cclimePortfolio" value = "CCPurple" />
                    <label for = "cclimePortfolio"> CCPurple </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccmustardPortfolio" value = "CCRed" />
                    <label for = "ccmustardPortfolio"> CCRed </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "cctealPortfolio" value = "CCTeal" />
                    <label for = "cctealPortfolio"> CCTeal </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccyellowPortfolio" value = "CCYellow" />
                    <label for = "ccyellowPortfolio"> CCYellow </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="CheckoxRow">
                Manager Name 2
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysblackPortfolio" value = "YSBack" />
                    <label for = "chkBlack">YSBlack</label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysbluePortfolio" value = "YSBlue" />
                    <label for = "chkBlue"> YSBlue </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysgoldPortfolio" value = "YSGold" />
                    <label for = "chkGold"> YSGold </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yslimePortfolio" value = "YSLime" />
                    <label for = "chkLime"> YSLime </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysolivePortfolio" value = "YSOlive" />
                    <label for = "chkOlive"> YSOlive </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yspinkPortfolio" value = "YSPink" />
                    <label for = "chkPink"> YSPink </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yspurplePortfolio" value = "YSPurple" />
                    <label for = "chkPurple"> YSPurple </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysredPortfolio" value = "YSRed" />
                    <label for = "chkRed"> YSRed </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ystealPortfolio" value = "YSTeal" />
                    <label for = "chkteal"> YSTeal </label>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                    <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysyellowPortfolio" value = "YSYellow" />
                    <label for = "chkYellow"> YSYellow </label>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="OK" /> -->
    <!-- <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="testResults(this.form)"> -->
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="map" </div>
```

**UPDATE**

I found some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798995/ways-to-pass-php-post-data-to-javascript)
So I updated my test function to look like this.

```
    function reloadResults(mapForm) 
    {
        alert("Hi There 1");
        var postData = <?php echo json_encode($_POST) ?>;
        alert(postData.blackPortfolio );
        alert(postData.limePortfolio);
        alert(postData.purplePortfolio);
    }
```

Now when I load the form and do a view source the  var postData line looks like this.

```
var postData = [];
```

After I click some boxes and click OK

It looks like this.

```
var postData = {"blackPortfolio":"Black","limePortfolio":"Lime","purplePortfolio":"Purple"};
```

It always seems to be one page load behind.
I'm obviously missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the function "downloadUrl".  The original example was doing a GET and I needed to be doing a POST

There is still one problem when I think I'm doing one to many round trips to the server and the resulting pins are being blanked out again.  I click on the Back button and like magic all the pins are shown.  I'll post this problem in a new question if I can't figure it out. (if I can I'll post it here)

This Code

```
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
```

Became This Code

```
request.open("POST", url, true)
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send(formString);
```

This article helped me find the answer http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Here is the full (almost) working HTML that includes any other changes I made in case someone else is trying to do the same thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <title>V.J. Ray Portfolio Map</title>
        <style>
            html, body 
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map 
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 350px; 
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
            .CheckBoxTable 
            {
                display: table; 
                width: 50%;
            }
            .CheckBoxRow {display: table-row; }
            .CheckBoxCell 
            {
                display: table-cell; 
                border: 1px solid #999999;
                padding: 1px 5px; 
            }
        </style>
        <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY-API-KEY>"
            type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var customIcons = 
        {
            Black:      {icon: 'pins/black.png'},
            Blue:       {icon: 'pins/blue.png'},
            Gold:       {icon: 'pins/gold.png'},
            Grey:       {icon: 'pins/grey.png'},
            Green:      {icon: 'pins/green.png'},
            Lime:       {icon: 'pins/lime.png'},
            Mustard:    {icon: 'pins/mustard.png'},
            Olive:      {icon: 'pins/olive.png'},
            Orange:     {icon: 'pins/orange.png'},
            Pink:       {icon: 'pins/pink.png'},
            Purple:     {icon: 'pins/purple.png'},
            Red:        {icon: 'pins/red.png'},
            Teal:       {icon: 'pins/teal.png'},
            Yellow:     {icon: 'pins/yellow.png'},
            CCBlack:    {icon: 'pins/ccblack.png'},
            CCBlue:     {icon: 'pins/ccblue.png'},
            CCGold:     {icon: 'pins/ccgold.png'},
            CCLime:     {icon: 'pins/cclime.png'},
            CCOlive:    {icon: 'pins/ccolive.png'},
            CCPink:     {icon: 'pins/ccpink.png'},
            CCPurple:   {icon: 'pins/ccpurple.png'},
            CCRed:      {icon: 'pins/ccred.png'},
            CCTeal:     {icon: 'pins/ccteal.png'},
            CCYellow:   {icon: 'pins/ccyellow.png'},    
            YSBlack:    {icon: 'pins/ysblack.png'},
            YSBlue:     {icon: 'pins/ysblue.png'},
            YSGold:     {icon: 'pins/ysgold.png'},
            YSLime:     {icon: 'pins/yslime.png'},
            YSOlive:    {icon: 'pins/ysolive.png'},
            YSPink:     {icon: 'pins/yspink.png'},
            YSPurple:   {icon: 'pins/yspurple.png'},
            YSRed:      {icon: 'pins/ysred.png'},
            YSTeal:     {icon: 'pins/ysteal.png'},
            YSYellow:   {icon: 'pins/ysyellow.png'},    
        };

        function load() 
        {
            // Draws the map with no pins initially
            //alert("Hi From Load");
            refreshMap();
        }

        function refreshMap()
        {
            //alert("Hi There from refreshMap()");
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9119, 151.1015),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            var formString=$("form").serialize();

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
            downloadUrl("GenerateXML.php",formString, function(data) 
{
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
                {
                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
                    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon
                    });
                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                }
            }); 
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url,formString, callback) {
            //alert("Hi There 3 downloadUrl (" + url  + "," + formString + "," + callback);
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) 
                {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };
            request.open("POST", url, true)
            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send(formString);
        }

        function doNothing() {}


        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="userForm" >

        <!-- <form name="mapForm" action="" onsubmit="return refreshMap()" method=""> <!-- This will call refreshMap()   Works if you use the back button -->
        <!-- <form action="GenerateXML.php" method="post"> -->          <!--This will output the XML to the browser window and test GenerateXML.php -->

        <form name="mapForm" action="" method="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend> <H2>Select Portfolio's to Display</h2></legend>
            <div class="CheckBoxTable">
                <div class="CheckoxRow">
                    General
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "blackPortfolio"  value = "Black" />
                        <label for = "blackPortfolio">Black</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "bluePortfolio"  value = "Blue" />
                        <label for = "bluePortfolio"> Blue </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "goldPortfolio" value = "Gold" />
                        <label for = "goldPortfolio"> Gold </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "greyPortfolio" value = "Grey" />
                        <label for = "greyPortfolio"> Grey </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "greenPortfolio" value = "Green" />
                        <label for = "greenPortfolio"> Green </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "limePortfolio" value = "Lime" />
                        <label for = "limePortfolio"> Lime </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "mustardPortfolio" value = "Mustard" />
                        <label for = "mustardPortfolio"> Mustard </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "olivePortfolio" value = "Olive" />
                        <label for = "olivePortfolio"> Olive </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "orangePortfolio" value = "Orange" />
                        <label for = "orangePortfolio"> Orange </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "pinkPortfolio" value = "Pink" />
                        <label for = "pinkPortfolio"> Pink </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "purplePortfolio" value = "Purple" />
                        <label for = "purplePortfolio"> Purple </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "redPortfolio" value = "Red" />
                        <label for = "redPortfolio"> Red </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "tealPortfolio" value = "Teal" />
                        <label for = "tealPortfolio"> Teal </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yellowPortfolio" value = "Yellow" />
                        <label for = "yellowPortfolio"> Yellow </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckoxRow">
                    Carolann Campbell
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccblackPortfolio" value = "CCBlack" />
                        <label for = "ccblackPortfolio">CCBlack</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccbluePortfolio" value = "CCBlue" />
                        <label for = "ccbluePortfolio"> CCBlue </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccgoldPortfolio" value = "CCGold" />
                        <label for = "ccgoldPortfolio"> CCGold </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "cclimePortfolio" value = "CCLime" />
                        <label for = "cclimePortfolio"> CCLime </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccolivePortfolio" value = "CCOlive" />
                        <label for = "ccolivePortfolio"> CCOlive </label>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccpinkPortfolio" value = "CCPink" />
                        <label for = "ccpinkPortfolio"> CCPink </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "cclimePortfolio" value = "CCPurple" />
                        <label for = "cclimePortfolio"> CCPurple </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccmustardPortfolio" value = "CCRed" />
                        <label for = "ccmustardPortfolio"> CCRed </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "cctealPortfolio" value = "CCTeal" />
                        <label for = "cctealPortfolio"> CCTeal </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ccyellowPortfolio" value = "CCYellow" />
                        <label for = "ccyellowPortfolio"> CCYellow </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="CheckoxRow">
                    Yuliya Sobol
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysblackPortfolio" value = "YSBlack" />
                        <label for = "chkBlack">YSBlack</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysbluePortfolio" value = "YSBlue" />
                        <label for = "chkBlue"> YSBlue </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysgoldPortfolio" value = "YSGold" />
                        <label for = "chkGold"> YSGold </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yslimePortfolio" value = "YSLime" />
                        <label for = "chkLime"> YSLime </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysolivePortfolio" value = "YSOlive" />
                        <label for = "chkOlive"> YSOlive </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="CheckBoxRow">
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yspinkPortfolio" value = "YSPink" />
                        <label for = "chkPink"> YSPink </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "yspurplePortfolio" value = "YSPurple" />
                        <label for = "chkPurple"> YSPurple </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">                  
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysredPortfolio" value = "YSRed" />
                        <label for = "chkRed"> YSRed </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ystealPortfolio" value = "YSTeal" />
                        <label for = "chkteal"> YSTeal </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                        <input type = "checkbox" class = "Portfolio" name = "ysyellowPortfolio" value = "YSYellow" />
                        <label for = "chkYellow"> YSYellow </label>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value = "OK">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map" </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

$.post is a jQuery [method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), but your script is missing the library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Assuming you are using jQuery, you code could look something like this

```
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="reloadResults()">

function reloadResults() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Portfolio");
    $.post('GenerateXML.php', {elements: elements}), function(xml) {
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
...
```

Comment: I got this working a few weeks ago and thought I'd better come back and tidy up this post.  I am using JQuery and added a line that points to a copy that I downloaded.  That way I know it won't go missing from some other server.  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>  The problem in the end turned out to be a bit different to your suggestion so I'll post my own answer.  Thanks for your assistance.